# cannot build docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, devops, alpine-linux

I have been trying to build a Docker image by using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:base-6

MAINTAINER techhadmin

COPY ./package.json src/

RUN cd src && npm install 

COPY . /src 

WORKDIR /src

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But I receive this error:

> /bin/sh: npm: not found
>   The command '/bin/sh -c cd src && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Read the docs:

https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/

Is written:

> # If you need npm, don't use a base tag
>
> # RUN npm install

So don't use `base-6` tag and change `FROM` image to something like `7`

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:7
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error message because when you tried to run `npm install`, there is no copy of `npm` available.

You are using `alpine` as the base image.

By default, `alpine` is a small image and so it has a limited set of default programs inside of it. What programs are in the `alpine` image? Not much.

So if you are trying to run an `alpine` image with Nodejs you need to do additional work.

To solve it, you have two options:

1. Find a different base image. - You can try to find a base image that already has Node and NPM inside of it.
2. Run `alpine` with some additional commands that attempts to install `npm` inside of it.

Use someone else's work or building it from scratch.

I recommend finding an image preconfigured with `npm` inside of it. You can navigate to DockerHub, which is a repository of images.

There is an official Node repository in DockerHub.

https://hub.docker.com/_/node

So you could do something like this:

```
# Specify base image
FROM node:alpine

# Install some dependencies
RUN npm install

# Setup default command
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The nice thing about `node:alpine` is that you will not get any additional unnecessary packages, just the absolute stripped down version of Nodejs and nothing else aside from the basics such as the `ping` command, `cat`, `ls` and so on.